# How to add multiple MX record from different Email server

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

I am using 4 mail services. Let say my domain is `example.com`

1. Amazon SES for Transactional Email - (Only Sending not receiving - SMTP)
2. Zoho Mail for workmail (Webmail) - (Users email, both sending and receiving with SMTP & IMAP)
3. Mailchimp for promotional and newsletter
4. [Modoboa](https://github.com/modoboa/modoboa/) installed on ubuntu (SMTP and IMAP)

```
@ MX 10 feedback-smtp.us-west-3.amazonses.com
@ MX 10 mx.zoho.in
@ MX 20 mx2.zoho.in
@ MX 50 mx.mailchimp.com
@ MX 10 mail.example.com.com
@ A  Mail 192.9.X.XX
```

Is this correct?.

Comment: I am sorry, but it looks like you have to take a base-course about this topic. This is really the basic of the basic when it comes to email.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, MX specifies what servers *other* mail servers should connect to to deliver mail to your domain. You should ***not*** list mailchimp or amazon in there, as they are used just for sending mail from your domain.

Second, if you list two MX servers with same priority, mail will not be delivered to both. It will be delivered to one of them. If a mail server with a lower priority (floating to the top) is down, one further down the list will be used.

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, but I would suggest that you read up on how e-mail works because your current setup seems fundamentally broken and confused, and likely to loose messages.

E-mail is one of the trickier services to host, as you have to ensure your messages is deliverable, you're not an open proxy, and adhere to standards such as SPF and DKIM. There's more to learn than what you need to smack up a web server.

Generally, you should probably not contemplate self-hosting your e-mail until you *understand* what you're doing. Based on what you write you do not understand e-mail or dns.

Comment: Amazon SES want us to set SMTP, CNAME and MX record right?

Comment: No. Please, sit down and read, and understand how e-mail works - what is the purpose of MX records? What is the purpose of SMTP? How does SPF and DKIM fit into the picture? If you try to host e-mail with the knowledge you have, you are in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I mean, if you google `amazon ses mx record`, you [get the help page where Amazon ***describes*** what an MX record is...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-mx-record.html). Ten minutes ago I was not aware what Amazon SES was, but I still found documentation.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. my mistake. So, MX record, SPF and DKIM is not required for sending mail. Only required for receiving. - right?. Yes, i am new to this field. sorry if my question feel not sense-able to you.

Comment: Please grab a book on the topic, or at very least read wikipedia pages on email, smtp, dns and related topics.